# feature detection for accepting timeslice in mediaRecorder.start(timeslice)

Tags: firefox, webrtc, feature-detection, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

Many browsers' Media Stream Recording API implementations offer a MediaRecorder class to accept streams from getUserMedia, compress them, and deliver them as Blobs. MediaRecorder offers a `start(timeslice)` method. It starts compressing the stream, then calls an `ondataavailable` handler about every `timeslice` milliseconds.

That's the theory, at least. But some browsers (I'm looking at you, Firefox) only call the handler every half-second or even whole second, the requested `timeslice` value notwithstanding. My particular application needs a shorter latency, so it can't use browsers with that defect.

Is there a clean feature-detection way to figure this out quickly? Or do I have to look at the User-Agent string?

Comment: Too narrow an interval is going to be counter-productive and force unnecessary key frames. That's why Firefox has a lower threshold. I'd question the use-case here, since `MediaRecorder` is geared toward storage, not real-time.

Comment: In Chrome, the interval has nothing to do with the frequency of video key frames in either H.264 or VP8/9. And MediaRecorder works very well indeed for the low-latency use case in Chrome.